# Cosine function curve

Tags: trigonometry

Is this curve called cosine curve? Because I have a reference that says it is. I googled the cosine curve and found something different.
[image]

Comment: Loosely speaking it might be described as "a cosine curve" but this is imprecise.  A more apt description would be a *biased* cosine (or *sinusoidal*) curve since some constant has been added to the function to shift it upward (in a positive direction) to avoid negative values.

Answer (score 2):

No, the cosine function has negative values too, which is not the case of your picture

Answer (score 1):

It is cosine curve modified by shifting up or simply squaring a sine curve.

$$ \dfrac{P}{P_m} = \dfrac {1- \cos { \dfrac{4 \pi t}{T}}}{2} = \sin ^2 \dfrac {2 \pi t}{T} $$

Answer (score 0):

The parent function of the function shown is a cosine (or sine) function, but it has been shifted both horizontally as well as vertically. I would more accurately state that function being of the *cosine family*.